# Refactoring in JavaScript - move function to another class

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I have the following JavaScript code in `current.js` file:

```
function S() {
    Srv.call(this);
}

S.prototype = Object.create(Srv.prototype);
S.prototype.constructor = S;

S.prototype.search = function (paramA) {}
```

I want to move it to another class, so that all the functionality of `S` will be in one separate class.

How can I do it? I try to find rules for this re-factoring, but I don't find anything.

Comment: what functionality ? the search method there ?

Comment: Yes. I have many methods of S which I want to move to other `js` file

Comment: move to other file or to other class? Just move them.

Comment: @Bergi To other class. I want that all function of S3 would be in another class, so current.js will be able to use it.

Comment: So what? Then move the methods on the prototype of that other class. Or do you mean that you still want to use them on `S`? Please show us your attempt.